# Unable to connect to Sybase15.7 :Cannot connect to server on host 'localhost': Permission denied

Tags: redhat, sap-ase, unixodbc, devart, php-7.0

I''m connecting PHP7 with Sybase15.7 using Devart drivers in RedHat Linux and getting the following error.
**

> SQLSTATE[08001] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Devart][ODBC][Adaptive
>   Server Enterprise] Cannot connect to server on host 'localhost':
>   Permission denied. Socket Error Code:13

**
Anybody help me to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the audit log for SELinux denials.  You probably need to run this command to grant PHP scripts unrestricted access to localhost:

```
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```